# Run executable during setup process with 3rd party dependencies

Tags: wix, windows-installer, cpack

I'm using WIX toolset to build up Windows installer package. The package includes a main software, a tool executable and some 3rd party dependencies.

For some reason I wish to run this tool executable right after all the files are copied during installation. I'm trying to use custom action with element [before=InstallFinalize] to do this but the executable needs to reference the 3rd party dependencies in the package.

Using Wix custom action to execute the tool executable, but found the 3rd party is not referenced so the command won't run.

How can I accomplish all of this in the installing procedure?